# C# Sql Incorrect syntax error

Tags: c#, sql

In the following command I get the exception

```
Incorrect syntax near 'TPA_Approved_Date'
```

What am I doing wrong?:

```
  SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
  sqlComm = myConnection.CreateCommand();
 sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE [MRT_MKT_BIDW].[biw].[CNX_TPA_Applied_F] 
                        SET TPA_Approver_Code='@Approver_Code' 
                        TPA_Approved_Date ='@Approved_Date'   
                        TPA_Approved_Flag='Y' WHERE 
                        MDM_Invoice_Date_Dim_Key='20150206'";
 sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approver_Code", Approver_Code);
 sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approved_Date", "2015-05-06 16:24:47.870");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't enclose your parameters in quotes - otherwise they will be treated as literals
2. separate the columns with commas:

   ```
   sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE [MRT_MKT_BIDW].[biw].[CNX_TPA_Applied_F] SET TPA_Approver_Code=@Approver_Code, TPA_Approved_Date =@Approved_Date, TPA_Approved_Flag='Y' WHERE MDM_Invoice_Date_Dim_Key='20150206'";
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Above answer is correct. But just wanted to mention, sometimes its quicker to not to use parameters (if you trust the values in variables). Like for example:

```
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
sqlComm = myConnection.CreateCommand();
sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE [MRT_MKT_BIDW].[biw].[CNX_TPA_Applied_F] 
                        SET TPA_Approver_Code='"+Approver_Code+"',
                        TPA_Approved_Date ='2015-05-06 16:24:47.870',
                        TPA_Approved_Flag='Y' WHERE 
                        MDM_Invoice_Date_Dim_Key='20150206'";
```

Comment: Bad idea.  Concatenation (especially with strings, but also with dates) can lead to all kind of errors, whether you "trust" the value or not.  It's not just about SQL injection - what if the value legitimately contains an apostrophe?

Comment: Can you give some examples for your "all sort of errors" considering the situation it is a trusted non null value?
It depends on situation I am not saying it is the best way forward, but it works well in some cases. Which means I seriously doubt you classification of this as BAD IDEA!

Comment: 1. Strings with apostrophes (`"O'Brien"`) 2. Assuming that the client and server represent dates in a compatible way (what date is "1/2/2015"in the US?  In England?)

Comment: You are passing the date as string anyway in question and in your answer!! so if it is wrong to concatenate, then its wrong in parameter too. Any other... ?

Comment: @ravish.hacker parameterized sql gets you more than just protection from simple errors (`O'Brian`) and sql injection, for sql server it also allows the server to reuse an old plan (if one exists) saving recompile time.  Lots of good reasons to use parameters and a couple really bad ones to not.

Comment: @ravish.hacker That value appears to be a string column, not a date column, so there may not be any risk of misinterpretation.  In any case, I was reusing the original query which has that value hard-coded - not concatenated from a variable. I'm not saying it's _always_ wrong but it's wrong often enough that I would not recommend someone change a parameterized query to a concatenated one.

Comment: And thus i mentioned it ahead of my (other but not main) option that what you suggested is right. I appreciate you answer and use the same approach. 
I think there is no point arguing, .Net adding those parameter for you to actual SQL (not to ignore internal .Net checks themselves) ultimately will add a little overhead. You might argue negligible but if iterated multiple times, could build up. Any way, thanks its good to discuss these things healthily.